# How to put condition on button in ionic

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I hae code of ecommerece page. i want to use a button if someone selected anything then it show Remove text on that button otherwise default name should be Add To cart. My code is as follow

```
<button
                *ngIf="!added"
                (click)="addToCart(cItem.id,i)"
                class="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Add to cart
              </button>
              <button
                *ngIf="added"
                (click)="removeitem(cItem.id,i)"
                class="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Remove
              </button>

            </div>
```

and .ts file is

```
addToCart(index,i) {debugger;
    this.added=true;
    this.dynamicArray.push(index);
    this.toasterService.Success('Item Added Successfully')
    return true;
  }
  removeitem(item: any,i) {debugger;
    this.added=false;
    const index = this.categoriesItem.findIndex(x => x.id === item);
   this.categoriesItem.splice(index, 1);
   console.log(this.added)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
<button (click)="checkCart(cItem.id,i)"class="btn btn-primary">{{ added == true ? 'Remove' : 'Add To cart' }}  </button>
```

**.ts**

```
checkCart(index,i) {
    if(this.added){
        const index = this.categoriesItem.findIndex(x => x.id === item);
        this.categoriesItem.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else{
        this.dynamicArray.push(index);
        this.toasterService.Success('Item Added Successfully')
        return true;
        this.added = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MalikRizwan what was an issue ? it would be great can you share your error

Comment: it not not showing any error on console. on screen ont Add to cart button appear. No 'Remove' button came while i click specific item